# React Native Firebase - State Not Able to be Retrieved on First Load

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm using `useEffect` to retrieve some user and group data on initial screen load on a `react-native` app. The following code for this is here:

```
const [groupInfo, setGroupInfo] = useState([]);
    //Called on INITIAL rendering
useEffect(() => {

    async function getGroupData() {

        let groupCode = '';

        //Retrieve group code from user
        await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', email)).then(userSnapshot => {

            if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
                groupCode = userSnapshot.data()['group_code'];

            }
            else { console.log('No user with that email exists!'); }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        //Retrieve group information from user
        await getDoc(doc(db, 'groups', groupCode)).then(groupSnapshot => {

            if (groupSnapshot.exists()) {
                setGroupInfo(groupSnapshot.data());
            }
            else { console.log('No group with that code exists!'); }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    getGroupData();

}, [email]);
```

The problem is that when I've tried to render this on my `return` statement, I get an error. I've logged my data before and that has worked fine but it seems that the app loads the view first. THe following react render code and error are below:

```
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.headerLeft}>Goals</Text>
            <Text style={styles.headerRight}>Week of 11/20/22</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.prize}>Prize: Winner gets a free starbucks drink!</Text>
        {/*<View style={styles.goalBox}>
            <Text>Workout 3x per week</Text>
            <CheckBox style={styles.checkbox}/>
        </View> */}

        {/* TODO edit prize screen */}
        <Button title="Edit prize" />


        <View style={styles.memberHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.headerLeft}>Members</Text>
            <Text style={styles.numMembers}>4</Text>
        </View>

        {
            groupInfo['members'].map((memberName, index) =>
                <View style={styles.member}>
                    <Text style={styles.memberText}>{memberName}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
        
        <Button title="Invite member" />
    </View>
);
```

Error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in ScreenViewGroup (created by SceneView)
```

EDIT:

So I think the problem is that at the same time the component is being rendered, the data is being loaded in. I'm still receiving the same error but I've noticed that when I edit my code, the data gets loaded in automatically.

Text strings also seem to render in properly as well but just not the array.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the map of groupInfo members. Have you tried logging the groupInfo (or groupInfo members) to console?

Comment: Please include your `useState` call for `groupInfo`.

Comment: @samthecodingman I never call useState. I've included my declaration at the top, I don't think that adds much

Comment: @dev404 So the rendering of the array works if the data is loaded up. However, it doesn't work initially. See my update on the post for more details

Comment: That declaration was what I was looking for. While it doesn't add much, it tells me that on the first render of the component, `groupInfo` is `[]`, an empty array. However when you fetch data from Firebase it is replaced with an object with the shape `{ members: ['name1', 'name2', ...], ...}`. On that first render, when there is no data, you should either return null from your component (telling react it's not ready to be displayed yet), show some form of loading message/symbol, or some placeholder information.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a work-around. By declaring my initial array with values, React will fill those values in as default values and immediately change them to the firebase values when they load.